# Unable to upload a github asset using Javascript

Tags: javascript, networking, github-api, http-status-code-400

## Overview

I'm attempting to upload asset to github using Javascript fetch request.  It works in Postman

### Postman

[image: Postman Query]

## Error

but in javascript I get this error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://uploads.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/{id}/assets?name=windows.zip. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 400.
```

I've been working on this for a few days now...
Thanks in advance

## Javascript CODE

```js
async function OpenFile() {
    let input = document.createElement("input")
    input.type = "file";
    input.accept = "application/zip";
    input.addEventListener("change", async e => {
        let file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            let content = reader.result;

            let myHeaders = new Headers();
            myHeaders.append("Authorization", `token *****`);
            myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/zip");
            myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/vnd.github+json");

            let requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: myHeaders,
                body: content,
                mode: 'cors'
            };
            fetch(`https://uploads.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/releases/{ID}/assets?name=file.zip`, requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
                }).catch(error => { console.log(error) })
        }, false)
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)

    })
    input.click();
}
```

P.S.
I removed sensitive information from the urls

### Edit:

Github API states that you should be able to use this

```js
// Octokit.js
// https://github.com/octokit/core.js#readme
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: 'personal-access-token123'
})

await octokit.request('POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/releases/{release_id}/assets{?name,label}', {
  owner: 'OWNER',
  repo: 'REPO',
  release_id: 'RELEASE_ID'
})
```

OR

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "token ******");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/zip");

var file = "<file contents here>";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: file,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://uploads.github.com/repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/releases/{ID}/assets?name=file.zip", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: I doubt you can do that from a browser